What is the origin of counting?
In A History of Mathematics by Boyer and Merzbach, it is noted in the first Chapter that

It is usually assumed that the subject arose in answer to practical needs, but anthropological studies suggest the possibility of an alternative origin.It has been suggested that the art of
counting arose in connection with primitive religious ritual and that the
ordinal aspect preceded the quantitative concept. In ceremonial rites
depicting creation myths, it was necessary to call the participants onto the
scene in a specific order,and perhaps counting was invented to take care of
this problem.

However, Boyer and Merzbach are also cautious about the claims they make, writing

We can make conjectures about what led people of the Stone Age to
count, to measure, and to draw. That the beginnings of mathematics are
older than the oldest civilizations is clear. To go further and categorically identify a specific origin in space or time, however, is to mistake
conjecture for history. It is best to suspend judgment on this matter and
to move on to the safer ground of the history of mathematics as found in
the written documents that have come down to us.

It appears that much of the anthropological studies with regards to the origin of mathematical concepts, such as counting, emerge from the qualitative analysis of artifacts rather than available written sources. I'm interested in studies / papers which attempt to root the analysis of these artifacts and their origins in political, economic, and material contexts. To be specific, are there any sources which attempt to do such an analysis on the origins of counting? I recognize that there is far less source material for history so long ago, and so there will necessarily be a heavily speculative element to it, but I am interested in something which is methodologically similar to E.P. Thompson's analysis in *Time, Work-Discipline, and Industrial Capitalism."

I'm not an expert but I suspect the ability to count pre-dates not only recorded history but quite possibily modern man. We know that animals are able to keep track of objects and know if an object is added or removed. So, it's possibly an inherent ability. We also have a site dedicated to the History of Science and Mathematics which has people more expert in those areas.

Voting to close as anthropology/archaeology is out of scope here. I also don't know what it would even mean to apply the methods of modern social history to pre-historic artifacts. This may be of interest though: https://www.laphamsquarterly.org/roundtable/early-history-counting

We have a built-in ability to grasp the quantity of small numbers of items called "subitizing" which allows most people to see 2 or 3 or 4 things and know at a glance (without counting) that there are 2 or 3 or 4 things there. The upper limit varies from person to person, but is not high: five or six is about the limit. It is likely that this is an old mammalian trait, as many animals seem to have some ability to grasp small quantities. Subitizing is not counting, but I can see how human social evolution in groups might have found counting a useful extension of the limited built-in ability.

Many animals, even such as crows, know how to count…

I've seen some Sociological discussion about the language that exists for numbers among isolated hunter-gatherers. IMHO that would make a good answer here, but I don't know OP's opinion on the matter.

@T.E.D. I would love to see it, thank you!

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=3057431927853358&id=1539494262980473&set=a.2159402430989650

I don't think this question (as I understand it) can be answered.

Our first real clues are a handful of curious, carved bones dating from the final few millennia of the three-​million-​year expanse of the Old Stone Age, or Paleolithic era.

. . .

All of which is reminiscent of writing, except that writing did not arrive until a scant 5,000 years ago—​and so, when the Lebombo bone was determined to be some 42,000 years old, it instantly became one of the most intriguing archaeological artifacts ever found. EarlyHistoryOfCounting

That's long before any written records.
The question seems to dismiss any analysis of artifacts, and require an analysis of  "political, economic, and material contexts" - but the only records we have are artifacts.
Perhaps I'm unclear on the distinction between qualitative analysis of artifacts and political, economic and material contexts of artifacts.
I'm not sure how we could analyze the political impacts of carved bones, and I'm not sure how the "economic and material" context differs from the qualitative analysis provided.  We can make suppositions about economic context of a bone based on other artifacts found, and I fail to see how the material context differs from the qualitative analysis.  I'm extremely skeptical of any form of political analysis prior to the written records (apart from a political context that is tightly coupled to the economic context)
Not sure what is being asked here, or how to answer it, but as stated, I'm skeptical that there is an answer to this question.  I think @killingtime has it right.

Thank you for your answer. I don't mean to dismiss the analysis of artifacts - to my understanding (and perhaps I'm wrong as I am very new to history before written records), historians have made detailed conclusions about the political structure of society in social contexts prior to written records. My intention was not to make a distinction between qualitative analysis of artifacts and political, economic, and material contexts, but rather to note an emphasized interest in analysis of artifacts which attempts to foreground that kind of analysis. My search is for academic papers here.

Lions can count. They listen to roars and if there's more of "them" than of "us" they back off.
My dogs can count. Simple tests with hiding treats.
The art of counting might be older than mankind.
